# Is it possible to configure Presto with SpringJPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, presto, presto-jdbc

Based on the below error is see , Presto does not seem to be a valid dataSource that is compatible with Spring JPA
Description:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.jpa.database' to org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database:
Property: spring.jpa.database
Value: presto
Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:101:22
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database
Action: Update your application's configuration. The following values are valid: DB2 DEFAULT DERBY H2 HANA HSQL INFORMIX MYSQL ORACLE POSTGRESQL SQL_SERVER SYBASE
```

Thoughts or advise please ?